# How to compare date from a form with date from db in django query?

Tags: django, django-2.0

I am trying to filter tours based on the date in Django 2.0, i.e. to show all the tours that start on or after June 01, 2019 (should be received from a form).
I have a model 'Tour':

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   Available = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Tick it if you still operate this tour")
```

And I have a model 'Departures':

```
class Departures(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DepartingDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    FinishingDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    DepartureStatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = DEPARTURE_STATUS, help_text="Select from the list")
    PlacesAvailable = models.BooleanField("Places avalable", default="True")
    DepartureGaranteed = models.BooleanField("Departure Garanteed", default="True")
```

I want the user should select a start date of the tour from the html form:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <input class="form-control" id="dateStart" name="DateStart" type="date"/>
</div>
```

I have a form in my models.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    Country = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    TourType = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    TourTheme = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    Duration = forms.IntegerField(required=False) #, blank=True
    Price = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False) #, blank=True
    DateStart = forms.DateField(required=False) #input_formats='%d/%m/%Y',
```

EDITED(added the view function):

```
def search_tours(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            Country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
            TourType = form.cleaned_data['TourType']
            TourTheme = form.cleaned_data['TourTheme']
            Duration = form.cleaned_data['Duration']
            Price = form.cleaned_data['Price']
            DateStart = form.cleaned_data['DateStart']


            #Convert the date format
            # DateStart = datetime.strptime(str(DateStart), '%Y-%m-%d')
            # DateStart.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
            # DateStart.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 

            departures = Departures.objects.all()

            myfilter = Q()
            if Country is not None:
                for c in Country:
                    myfilter &= Q(destination__Country__icontains=c)


            if TourType is not None: 
                myfilter &=  Q(TourType__contains=TourType) 

            if TourTheme is not None:
                myfilter &= Q(TourTheme__contains=TourTheme) 

            if Duration is not None:
                myfilter &= Q(Duration__lte=Duration) 

            if Price in request.GET:
                myfilter &= Q(Price__lte=Price)

            if DateStart in request.GET:
                myfilter &= Q(Departures__DepartingDate__gt=DateStart)

            tours = Tour.objects.filter(myfilter)

            paginator = Paginator(tours, 3) # Show 3 tours per page
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            tours = paginator.get_page(page)


            args = {'tours': tours, 'departures': departures,  
                                    'Country': Country,
                                    'TourType': TourType,
                                    'TourTheme': TourTheme,
                                    'Price' : Price,
                                    'Duration' : Duration,
            }
            return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html',  args)

        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../error/')
    else:
        form = SearchTourForm()

    tours = Tour.objects.filter(Available = True)
    return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html', {
        'tours': tours,
    })
```

So I am trying to filter the tours like below:

```
tours = Tour.objects.filter(Q(Departures__DepartingDate__gt=DateStart))
```

But it is not working. I guess the problem is that the html form date format and the  django db date format are not matching. It does not give an error, but it does not filter. Just shows all the tour.

How can I bring those two dates to the same format and compare? How to fix this bug?

Comment: Can you share your *view*? How exactly do you capture the data?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have just added the view. Please have a look again. I want to mention that I have removed some part of the code which does not have problem. I can filter by Country, TourType, TourTheme etc, but just the date filter is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

So what I did to solve the question was that I change the model name from 'Departure' to 'departure':

```
if DateStart is not None:
      myfilter &= Q(departures__DepartingDate__gt=DateStart)
```

I also changed the condition for the above if statement from

```
if DateStart in request.GET:
```

to

```
if DateStart is not None:
```

Have a nice time! ;)